# Simple mod_rewrite and website dir structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory-structure

I am making a site with photo albums for agents.
Each agent has his folder with .css file.
Each agent dir has album folders with index.php and .css

```
/example.com/
    /agent001/
    agent001.css
        /000005/
        index.php
        main.css
        /photos/
            aaa.jpg
            bbb.jpg
        /000006/
        index.php
        ...
    /agent002/
    agent002.css
        /000009/
        ...
```

So the path to agent's 000005 album would be: `/agent001/000005/index.php`

I want a shortcut like: `/000005/` which forwards to `/agent001/000005/some-title-here`

Another thing I can't really get my head around is my dir structure.
I really need the agent and album folders to organize my stuff.
But index.php and main.css are all the same, should I move these files to the root?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Quick question: why does `site.com/000005/` redirect to `site.com/agent001/000005/some-title-here` but not `site.com/agent002/000005/some-title-here` (different agent)?

Comment: hi, yes because it is a different agent. Agent001 only owns 000005 and 000006 albums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with mod_rewrite. You would need some program that walks through the agent directories an checks if there is a folder with that name.

But besides that your short URLs would not be distinct any more. Because like [Max S. said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239222#comment-21955722), how should `/000005/` be mapped if more than one agent has an album “000005”? Or is this value unique for all agents?

And using a central instance of *index.php* and *main.css* is the best choice to avoid redundancy and complexity. In that case you could use mod_rewrite to rewrite requests to your central files like:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/index\.php$ /index.php
```

Comment: sorry I didn't make that clear.. /000005/ is only owned by agent001.
All the these album folders are unique (they are actually the date of the photoshoot)
Thanks for the answer about centralizing index.php and main.css